# Is Thomas of Aquinas's idea of 'beatification' still held?

Tags: heaven, resurrection, thomas-aquinas, infinity, new-earth

If so, how can we agree that man will only reach the end he was meant to enjoy by achieving the highest happiness, where there is nothing left to want or can be had...if we assume we shall remain finite and therefore only recieve finite pleasures?

I guess another way of asking 'how can we enoy the infinite Lord (as Thomas suggested) if we can only bear witness in a finite fashion? If our joy is 'less' how can it be that nothing is left to desire?

Comment: This IS only one question, really. I confused myself rereading it! It's asking, given the seeming difference of the two ideas, is the first still held?

Comment: Can you find a source for your quote? (AFAIK, there are only two things St. Thomas Aquinas was wrong about)

Comment: The wikipedia article on beatification has a few links to different 'bits' of Aquinas on the subject. Wish I could be more specific but I'm new to Aquinas (I'm only 22) so it will take a while until I'm up to speed. Out of interest, what two things was he wrong about?

Comment: One was the Immaculate Conception and I don't remember what the other one was. (I don't think it was this though)